# Distributed chained computing with Dask on a high failure-rate cluster?

Tags: python, mapreduce, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I am using `Dask` Bag to run some simple map-reduce computation on a *special* cluster:

```py
import dask.bag as bag

summed_image = bag.from_sequence(my_ids).map(gen_image_from_ids).reduction(sum, sum).compute()
```

This code generates a chained computation, starts mapping from `from_sequence` and `gen_image_from_ids`, and then reduces all results into one with `sum`'s. Thanks to Dask Bag's feature, the summation is done in parallel in a multi-level tree.

My *special* cluster setting has higher failure rate because my worker can be killed anytime and the CPU is taken over by other higher-order processes and then released after a while. The killing may occur once on only a single node per 5 minutes, but my total reduction job may take more than 5 minutes.

Although Dask is good at failure recovery, my job sometimes just never ends. Consider if any internal node in the job tree gets killed, the temporary intermediate results from all previous computations are missing. And the computation should restart from beginning.

There is [replicate](http://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/api.html#distributed.Client.replicate) for Dask Future objects but I could not find similar feature on higher-level Dask Bag or Dataframe to ensure data resiliency. Please let me know if there is a common treatment to keep intermediate results in a Dask cluster with super-high failure rate.

#### Update - My workaround

Maybe any distributed computing system will suffer from frequent failures even though the system can recover from them.  In my case the worker shutdown is not essentially system failure, but is triggered by the higher-order process. So instead of directly killing my workers, the higher-order process now launches a small python script to send [retire_worker()](http://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/api.html#distributed.Client.retire_workers) command, when it starts running.

As documented, by `retire_worker()` scheduler will move data from the retired worker to another one available. So my problem is temporarily solved.  However, I sill leave the question open since I think replicated, redundant computing would be a faster solution, and better use idle nodes in the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the solution you are looking for, but one option is to divide up the task sequence into small-enough batches that can ensure that the task will complete in time (or will be quick to re-do from scratch).

Something like this perhaps:

```py
import dask.bag as db
from toolz import partition_all

n_per_chunk = 100 # just a guess, the best number depends on the case
tasks = list(partition_all(n_per_chunk, my_ids))

results = []
for t in tasks:
    summed_image = (
        db
        .from_sequence(my_ids)
        .map(gen_image_from_ids)
        .reduction(sum, sum)
        .compute()
    )
    results.append(summed_image)

summed_image = sum(results) # final result
```

There are other things to keep in mind here regarding re-starting the workflow on failure (or potentially launching smaller tasks in parallel), but hopefully this gives you a starting point for a workable solution.

Comment: I tried your code but it is slow because the summed_images are generated in sequential manner. However, this is inspiring. I think one way is to replace .compute() in your code to non-blocking .persist() and collect the results once any is available.

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to go from here... which way is better will depend on specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: More trials later -- this answer is not ideal because `client.replicate()` command is blocking. I suspect it requires all futures to be done before making replica -- this is unwanted because 1. any intermediate node can disconnect before all are ready, and 2. it prevents other tasks to run asynchronously. I need other way to make replica.

After lots of trials, I found one way to replicate the intermediate results during chained computation to realize data redundancy. Note the parallel `reduction` function is a Dask `Bag` feature, which does not directly support `replicate` facility. However, as Dask document states, one can [replicate](http://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/api.html#distributed.Client.replicate) low-level Dask `Future` objects to improve resiliency.

Following @SultanOrazbayev's post to manually perform partial sums, with [persist](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.bag.Bag.persist.html)() function to keep partial sums in cluster memory as in the comment, the returned item is essentially a Dask `Future`:

```py
import dask.bag as db
from dask.distributed import futures_of
from toolz import partition_all

n_per_chunk = 100 # just a guess, the best number depends on the case
tasks = list(partition_all(n_per_chunk, my_ids))

bags = []
for t in tasks:
    summed_image = (
        db
        .from_sequence(my_ids)
        .map(gen_image_from_ids)
        .reduction(sum, sum)
        .persist()
    )
    bags.append(summed_image)

futures = futures_of(bags)  # This can only be called on the .persist() result
```

I can then replicate these remote intermediate partial sums and feel safer to `sum` the futures to get final result:

```py
client.replicate(futures, 5) # Improve resiliency by replicating to 5 workers
summed_image = client.submit(sum, futures).result()  # The only line that blocks for the final result
```

Here I feel replica of 5 is stable for my cluster, although higher value will incur higher network overhead to pass the replica among workers.

This works but may be improved, like how to perform parallel reduction (sum) on the intermediate results, especially when there are lots of tasks. Please leave me your suggestions.